# Undefined method map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4 application that I'm trying to get to work with elasticsearch. Before I added the Elasticsearch, my code worked fine, but now I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

My index view (I use haml):

```
= form_tag products_path, :method => :get do
  = text_field_tag :query, params[:query]
  = submit_tag "Search", :name => nil

= render "table"
```

and here is my _table partial:

```
- headers = @products.map(&:data).flat_map(&:keys).uniq

%table
  %tr
    - headers.each do |key|
       %th= key

  - @products.each do |product|
    %tr
      - headers.each do |key|
         %td= product.data[key]
```

My ProductsController#index

```
def index
  if params[:query].present?
     Product.search(params[:query])
  else
     @products = Product.all.where(:product_type_id => @product.id)
  end
end
```

My model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 include Tire::Model::Search
 include Tire::Model::Callbacks

 belongs_to :product_type

end
```

Thanks!

Comment: The error means you've got an uninitialized value that you think is an initialized array calling the `map` method. If `params[:query].present?` is true, then `@products` won't be initialized, and you're calling `@products.map...` in your `_table` partial with an uninitialized value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `@products` will be nil if there is a query present. I think you meant to do something like this:

```
  if params[:query].present?
     @products = Product.search(params[:query])
  else
     @products = Product.all.where(:product_type_id => @product.id)
  end
```